# Show specific text from a php loop of database results using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have selected data from my database and I have looped through the results to display them on my page. I have 3 results which are shown. Each result has a button with an id called decrease. When I click this button, an alert with the name of the item containing the alert button should be displayed. I am using jQuery to achieve this.

My problem is that whenever I click the button, the name of only the first item in the results array is displayed. The buttons in the other two results don't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

The code that loops through the result and displays the items in the database table:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($run) >= 1){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $quantity = $row['quantity'];
        $price = $row['price'];
        $image = $row['image'];
        $category = $row['category'];
        $total = $price * $quantity;
        echo "<div class=\"post-container\">\n";
        echo "<div class=\"post-thumb\">\n";
        echo "<img src='$image'>\n";
        echo "</div>\n";
        echo "<div class=\"post-title\">\n";
        echo "<h4 style=\"font-weight:bold;\">\n";
        echo "<a href=\"view.php?name=$name&category=$category\" class=\"links\" target=\"_blank\">$name</a>\n";
        echo "<span id=\"deletion\">Delete</span>\n";
        echo "</h4>\n";
        echo "</div>\n";
        echo "<div class=\"post-content\">\n";
        echo "<ul style=\"list-style-type:none;\">\n";
        echo "<li>Cost Per Item: <span id=\"cost\">$price</span>/=</li>\n";
        echo "<li>\n";
        echo "Quantity: \n";
        echo "<button type=\"submit\" id=\"decrease\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\" title=\"Decrease Quantity\"></button>\n";
        echo "\n";
        echo "<span id=\"cost\" class=\"quantity\">&nbsp$quantity&nbsp</span>\n";
        echo "\n";
        echo "<button type=\"submit\" id=\"increase\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-plus\" title=\"Increase Quantity\"></button>\n";
        echo "</li>\n";
        echo "<li>Total Cost: <span id=\"cost\">$total</span>/=</li>\n";
        echo "</ul>\n";
        echo "</div>\n";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

And here's the jquery:

```
$("#decrease").click(function(){
    var name = $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent("div.post-content").siblings("div.post-title").find("a").text();
    alert(name);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML markup is invalid as there can be only one element with given id - id must be unique. You can use classes instead, for example class `decrease` will have selector `.decrease`, that will pertain to all your buttons.

Comment: Never knew id must be unique. I always thought it worked in the same way as a class but only as an alternative. Thank you very much, I converted it into a class and it worked